# Python counting number of files and directories recursively

Tags: python, recursion, io

I'm trying to get the number of files and folders in a directory. I found os.walk() and it does what for only the root directory. I tried the following but I need to create two list and check if it is file or folder and count them.

```
pathlib.Path(src).glob('**/*')
```

I can't find a simple and effective way to do a simple task like that. I feel like I'm missing something here. Any suggestions?

Comment: `os.walk` works. What did you try?

Comment: I tried it with `x, y, z = os.walk(src)` but I get 

`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

If I use it with next(walk(src)) I need to iterate of all to get a total number. Correct me If I'm wrong please.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [*map(lambda x: x.is_dir(), pathlib.Path(src).rglob('*'))]
sum(lst), len(lst) - sum(lst)  # number of dirs, number of files
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

`os.walk` is a generator, you need to iterate its results:

```py
{p: {"directories": len(directories),
     "files": len(files)}
 for p, directories, files in os.walk(root_dir)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.walk()`.  It recursively iterates a directory and for each iteration returns a directory path and the number of files and directories at that path.  Just total them up:

```py
import os

dirs_cnt = 0
files_cnt = 0

for path,dirs,files in os.walk('.'):  # Current directory
    dirs_cnt += len(dirs)
    files_cnt += len(files)

print(f'Total: dirs={dirs_cnt} files={files_cnt}')
```